# Postgres search JSON by dynamic value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, search, jsonb

In Postgres 14, I'm trying to query a JSON array element:

```
{
  "haystack": [
    { "search": "findthis" },
    { "search": "someothervalue" }
  ]
}
```

This works:

```
SELECT 1
FROM test
WHERE data->'haystack' @> '[{"search":"findthis"}]';
```

However, when "findthis" comes from a function: `getText()` or some other dynamic value, I get 0 results:

```
SELECT 1
      FROM test
      WHERE data->'haystack' @> to_jsonb('[{"search":"' || getText()::text || '"}]');
```

(I am expecting to return 1)

My test:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ed2615fe9be7a5b0284065f49fddd36f

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb`, not `to_jsonb`

```sql
select to_jsonb('[{"search":"' || 'findthis' || '"}]'), jsonb('[{"search":"' || 'findthis' || '"}]')
```

and your query with type cast

```sql
SELECT 1
      FROM test
      WHERE data->'haystack' @> ('[{"search":"' || 'findthis' || '"}]')::jsonb;
```